# How do you simulate a QPushButton press using code

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I want to have the handler for a button click simulate another button click is there a way to do this using the native signal/slot? My test code (the behavior I'm looking for) when click on button #1 should execute #1 handler and send a button press (signal) from button #2 which execute #2 handler and send a button press (signal) from button #1 and repeat. The errors follow the two things I have tried:

```
import time
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication


class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Button 1", self)
        self.btn1.move(30, 50)

        self.btn2 = QPushButton("Button 2", self)
        self.btn2.move(150, 50)

        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.button1Clicked)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.button2Clicked)

        self.statusBar()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event sender')
        self.show()

    def button1Clicked(self):

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Button #1 was pressed')
        time.sleep(5)
        self.btn2.emit()        # QPushButton' object has no attribute 'emit'
        self.btn2.clicked()     # native Qt signal is not callable

    def button2Clicked(self):

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Button #2 was pressed')
        time.sleep(5)
        self.btn1.emit()
        self.btn1.clicked()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Some feedback???

Answer (score 2):

You should not use time.sleep as it blocks the GUI event loop. If you want to emit the clicked signal after a time T then you must invoke `button.clicked.emit()` with a QTimer:

```
QTimer.singleShot(T, lambda: button.clicked.emit())
```

that can be simplified to:

```
QTimer.singleShot(T, button.clicked.emit)
```

In your case:

```
def button1Clicked(self):
    self.statusBar().showMessage("Button #1 was pressed")
    QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.btn2.clicked.emit)

def button2Clicked(self):
    self.statusBar().showMessage("Button #2 was pressed")
    QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.btn1.clicked.emit)
```

On the other hand it is recommended that the signal be emitted only within the class to which the signal belongs, so in the case of the buttons you can use the [`click()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#click) method to do the same:

```
def button1Clicked(self):
    self.statusBar().showMessage("Button #1 was pressed")
    QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.btn2.click)

def button2Clicked(self):
    self.statusBar().showMessage("Button #2 was pressed")
    QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.btn1.click)
```

That will cause the signal to be emitted but the effect of pressing on the button will not be seen, if you want to see the effect then you must use the [animateClick()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#animateClick) method:

```
def button1Clicked(self):
    self.statusBar().showMessage("Button #1 was pressed")
    QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.btn2.animateClick)

def button2Clicked(self):
    self.statusBar().showMessage("Button #2 was pressed")
    QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.btn1.animateClick)
```

Another way is using sending QMouseEvent to the widget:

```py
def send_mouse_event(widget, timeout=100):
    lp = widget.rect().center()
    press_event = QMouseEvent(
        QEvent.MouseButtonPress, lp, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier
    )
    QCoreApplication.postEvent(widget, press_event)
    release_event = QMouseEvent(
        QEvent.MouseButtonRelease, lp, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier
    )
    QTimer.singleShot(
        timeout, lambda: QCoreApplication.postEvent(widget, release_event)
    )
```

```
def button1Clicked(self):
    self.statusBar().showMessage("Button #1 was pressed")
    QTimer.singleShot(5000, lambda: send_mouse_event(self.btn2))

def button2Clicked(self):
    self.statusBar().showMessage("Button #2 was pressed")
    QTimer.singleShot(5000, lambda: send_mouse_event(self.btn1))
```

Another solution is using QtTest.QTest:

```
from PyQt5.QtTest import QTest
# ...
class Example(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def button1Clicked(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Button #1 was pressed")
        QTimer.singleShot(
            5000, lambda: QTest.mouseClick(self.btn2, Qt.LeftButton, delay=100)
        )

    def button2Clicked(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Button #2 was pressed")
        QTimer.singleShot(
            5000, lambda: QTest.mouseClick(self.btn1, Qt.LeftButton, delay=100)
        )
```